# D3 SVG right align vertical text above the bars in the bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, bar-chart

I am trying to add "labels" or rather text above the rects in the bar chart, and while the ones below the x axis appear just fine, the ones that are supposed to be above it are not aligned evenly. If you mentally draw the line on which all of the words that are located above the x axis start - it is all jagged. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? I am using SVG's  .style("writing-mode", "tb") and "text-anchor" : "end" for the labels above the axis.

Here is the picture
[image: Bar plot with uneven labels above x axis]

And here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Page Template</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./d3/d3.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .barplot{
                padding: 30px;
            }       
                    .axis path,
                    .axis line {
                        fill: none;
                        stroke: black;
                        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
                    }

                    .axis text {
                        font-family: sans-serif;
                        font-size: 11px;
                    }
                </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var skill_diff_data;
            var padding = 30;
            d3.json("./data/skill_diff_in_positions.json", function(error, data) {
                if (error) {  //If error is not null, something went wrong.
                    console.log(error);  //Log the error.
                    } else { 
                        skill_diff_data = data;
                    var keys = Object.keys(skill_diff_data);
                    var position_name = keys[0];
                    var diff_1 = skill_diff_data[position_name].perc_difference;
                    var w = 900;
                                var h = 500;
                                var svg2 = d3.select("body")
                                    .append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", w)
                                    .attr("height", h)
                                    .attr("class", "barplot");

                                var x0 = Math.max(-d3.min(diff_1), d3.max(diff_1)); 

                                var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                                                            .domain(d3.range(diff_1.length))
                                                            .rangeRoundBands([0, w], .05)

                                var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                                            .domain([- x0, x0])
                                                            .range([0, h]);

                              var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                                  .scale(xScale)
                                  .orient("bottom") 

                                svg2.selectAll("rect")
                                   .data(diff_1)
                                   .enter()
                                   .append("rect")
                                   .attr({
                                    x: function(d, i) { return xScale(i)},
                                    y: function(d) { 
                                        if( d > 0){
                                            return h - yScale(d);
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            return yScale(0);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    width: xScale.rangeBand(),
                                    height: function(d) {
                                        return Math.abs(yScale(d) - yScale(0));
                                    },
                                    fill: function(d, i) {
                                        if (d > 0){
                                            return "rgb("+ ((i-5) * 10) + ", " + ((i+5) * 10) + ", " + 0 + ")";
                                        } else {
                                            return "rgb(" + (i * 10) + " ," + ((diff_1.length - i)*10) + ", " + 0 + ")";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    });

                                 svg2.selectAll("text")
                               .data(diff_1)
                               .enter()
                               .append("text")
                               .text(function(d, i){return skill_diff_data[position_name].skills[i];})
                               .attr({
                                "text-anchor": function(d){
                                    if (d > 0){
                                        return "start";
                                    } else {
                                        return "end";
                                    }
                                },
                                x: function(d, i) {return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;},
                                y: function(d) { 
                                        if (d > 0){ 
                                            return h/2 + 10; 
                                        } else { 
                                            return h/2;
                                        }
                                    },
                                "font-family": "sans-serif",
                                "font-size": "11px",
                                fill: "black"
                                })
                               .style("writing-mode", "tb")

                               var axisElements = svg2.append("g")
                                    .attr("class", "axis")
                                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h/2 + ")")
                                    .call(xAxis);

                                axisElements.selectAll("text").remove();
                }

            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: so I "kind of fixed it" (along with some other things), and it feels like a totally backwards way to do it, but it works.... I would love to hear about how I can do it better, because there surely should be a way. I guess the major problem is that I still do not understand how the rotation works. I tried to leave the text as tick labels instead of adding text independently, and I could not make it align. Anyway - here is my current version - please let me know how to do it properly.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Page Template</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./d3/d3.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .barplot{
                padding: 30px;
            }       
                    .axis path,
                    .axis line {
                        fill: none;
                        stroke: black;
                        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
                    }

                    .axis text {
                        font-family: sans-serif;
                        font-size: 11px;
                    }
                </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var skill_diff_data;
            var padding = 30;
            d3.json("./data/skill_diff_in_positions.json", function(error, data) {
                if (error) {  //If error is not null, something went wrong.
                    console.log(error);  //Log the error.
                    } else { 
                        skill_diff_data = data;
                    var keys = Object.keys(skill_diff_data);
                    var position_name = keys[0];
                    var diff_1 = skill_diff_data[position_name].perc_difference;
                    var w = 900;
                                var h = 500;
                                var svg2 = d3.select("body")
                                    .append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", w)
                                    .attr("height", h)
                                    .attr("class", "barplot");

                                var x0 = Math.max(-d3.min(diff_1), d3.max(diff_1)); 

/*                              var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                                                            .domain(d3.range(diff_1.length))
                                                            .rangeRoundBands([0, w], .05)*/
                                var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                                                            .domain(d3.range(diff_1.length))
                                                            .rangeRoundBands([0, w], .05)

                                var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                                            .domain([- x0, x0])
                                                            .range([h, 0]);

                              var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                                  .scale(xScale)
                                  .orient("bottom") 

                                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(yScale)
                  .orient("left")
                  .tickValues(d3.range(- Math.floor(x0), Math.floor(x0), 1).filter(function (x){
                    return (x % 5 == 0);
                  }))

                                svg2.selectAll("rect")
                                   .data(diff_1)
                                   .enter()
                                   .append("rect")
                                   .attr({
                                    x: function(d, i) { return xScale(i)},
                                    y: function(d) { 
                                        if( d > 0){
                                            return yScale(d);
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            return yScale(0);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    width: xScale.rangeBand(),
                                    height: function(d) {
                                        return Math.abs(yScale(d) - yScale(0));
                                    },
                                    fill: function(d, i) {
                                        if (d > 0){
                                            return "rgb("+ ((i-5) * 10) + ", " + ((i+5) * 10) + ", " + 0 + ")";
                                        } else {
                                            return "rgb(" + (i * 10) + " ," + ((diff_1.length - i)*10) + ", " + 0 + ")";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    });

                                 svg2.selectAll("text")
                               .data(diff_1)
                               .enter()
                               .append("text")
                               .text(function(d, i){return skill_diff_data[position_name].skills[i];})
                               .attr({
                                "text-anchor": function(d){
                                    if (d > 0){
                                        return "end";
                                    } else {
                                        return "start";
                                    }
                                },
                                x: function(d, i) {return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;},
                                y: function(d) { 
                                        if (d > 0){ 
                                            return h/2 + 10; 
                                        } else { 
                                            return h/2;
                                        }
                                    },
                                "transform": function(d, i){
                                    if (d > 0){
                                        return "rotate (-90 " + (xScale(i)+ 1.3 * xScale.rangeBand() / 2) + ", " + (h/2 + 10)  +")";
                                    } else {
                                        return "rotate (-90 " + (xScale(i)+ 0.8 * xScale.rangeBand() / 2) + ", " + (h/2 - 5)  +")";
                                    }
                                }, 
                                "font-family": "sans-serif",
                                "font-size": "11px",
                                fill: "black"
                                })
                               /*.style("writing-mode", "tb")*/

                            var axisElements = svg2.append("g")
                                    .attr("class", "axis")
                                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h/2 + ")")
                                    .call(xAxis);

                                axisElements.selectAll("text").remove();

                                svg2.append("g")
                                .attr("class", "axis")
                                .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + ",0)")
                                .call(yAxis);


                }

            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm, have you tried rotating the text instead?

Comment: I tried, but I could not figure out how to do it properly... suggestions would be appreciated - I will try anything =)

Comment: Should be as simple as adding a `transform` and setting `dy` accordingly, see http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4403522

Comment: yeah... cannot make transform work... removed style and added           "dy": ".35em", "transform": "rotate(-90)" inside attr - the text is not rotated at all.

Comment: It would help if you could add a complete example.

Comment: I added the edit, something about text position changes when you add the transform, I am struggling to understand what is happening =/

Comment: okay, turns out it rotates around the origin and not x,y... so I am working on it

Comment: please see the update

Comment: So it does what you want now?

Comment: yes, but it feels hacky... I pretty much tried a bunch of combinations of the rotation coordinates treating text as either axis labels or separate text additions, and I found one combo that worked.... surprisingly it even works for different data and resets everything correctly and still in place... So I guess I am just going to leave it this way for now, but any better suggestions are appreciated..

Comment: Well the position you want to rotate about is determined by the bounding box of the text, so you could use `.getBBox()` on the DOM element to get that and use it for the rotation.

Comment: okay... I will try that...